# Validation rules are preventing using batch class

Tags: apex, batch

Need help to preventing validationrules while running the batch class.We have around 20 validation rules from opportunity out of 20,13 validation rules are are stopping using custom settings which is fine,remaining 7 validation-rules we are satisfying the conditions and updating opportunity accordingly using try catch blocks which is fine.

Main problem is if some one is adding new validation rule or changing any thing from existing one our batch won't work as expect if am not wrong. So please suggest me how to run succefull my batch if changes are coming from validation rules or creating new one?

Thanks

Comment: You need to rethink your reasons for the validation rules or apply then better if they are causing that much trouble.

Comment: @Eric ,Thanks for reply me.. I didn't get you ,could you please explain clearly. Thanks

Comment: @walter sfdc, How did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few options you have, most of them are outlined here. There are also some great comments on this article which might help.

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/bypass-validation-rules-from-apex.html